# OCaml taking a list to form a list of list with constraints

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, nested-loops

I'm trying to write a function that takes a list of binary numbers and returns a list of lists as follow: it must iterate over the initial list and can either add a nested list of *n* ones, up to *n-1* ones ending with a zero or a single zero. For example (with n = 3) :

```
[1;1;1;1;0;0] -> [[1;1;1];[1;0];[0]]
[1;1;1]       -> [[1;1;1]]
[1;0;0;1;1;0] -> [[1;0];[0];[1;1;0]]
```

The code i have so far is

```
let bitListSequence binList n =
  let rec aux acc binList =
  match binList with
  | []    -> acc
  | x::xs ->
    let rec loop acc2 = function
      | 1 -> if List.length acc2 < n-1 then loop acc2::1 xs
             else aux acc2 xs
      | 0 -> aux acc2::0 xs in
    aux [] acc
```

I think the logic is good but the syntax is incorrect. I'm trying to accumulate a nested list into `acc2` until a condition is met before appending it to `acc` and repeating the process until `binList` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You have a definition of a function named `aux` but no call to the function.
The body of `binList` looks roughly like this:

```
let rec aux acc binlist =
    (* Definition of aux *)
```

That's it. There's no `in` associated with this `let`, and hence no call to `aux`.

Comment: Is it possible to accomplish what i am trying to do with 2 accumulators running simultaneously ?

Comment: It's hard to answer this question. It seems to me you can have a single accumulator that is a list of lists and a count of the number of 1's in the most recent list. At the end you can reverse all the lists, and the outer list. That's probably how I would start out. If you call the count an accumulator, that's two accumulators.